# Lambda calculus: Apply in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I imagined this would work. Am I doing something clearly wrong?

```
val apply = (f: Any => Any, v: Any) => f(v)
val square = (x: Int) => x * x
```

I imagined apply(square, 10) would result in 100.

But I get an error:

```
:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Int
 required: Any => Any
       apply(square, 100)
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Functions are covariant in their return types, but contravariant in arguments. 
`Int => Int` is a subclass of `Int => Any`, but not of `Any => Int` or `Any => Any` (if it was, you could use in a context where, for example, a `String` parameter is passed in, and it would not be able to handle it, because it wants an `Int`).

Cosider this:

```
val foo: Function[Int, Int] = { x => x * x }    
def bar(f: Any => Any)(arg: Any): Any = f(arg) 

bar(foo)("foo") //???
```

The if `Int => Int` was a subclass of `Any => Any`, then the last line would be valid. But it cannot be, because it would result in `foo` being called with a `String` parameter.

Note, on the other hand, that `Any => Int` is a subclass of `Int => Int` (you can use the former anywhere the latter is required). This is what being "contravariant" means.

Comment: Worth adding: if you change the definition of `apply` (in the question) to `def apply[T] = (f: T => T, v: T) => f(v)`, it would work, because this way the types of v, f's input and f's output are known to be the same type.

Comment: @TzachZohar   Not because they are "known to be the same type" (that is the case with the original example as well), but rather because `apply[Any]` and `apply[Int]` are essentially two different functions in this case.

Comment: @Dima, if functions are contravariant in their arguments, can I say that Any => Int is a subclass of Int => Int?

Comment: @RodrigoStv yes, you can. In fact, that is exactly what I said in the last paragraph of my answer ;)